# Audio output broadcasting and Force Routing - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to build a broadcast that every time audio output route is changed it would route it to a device of choice instead (both in calls and when playing media/music).

for example: when getting a call with plugged/Bluetooth headset and then the user decides to click on the speaker icon on the phone, I need the app to route it back to the headset.

I succeeded to change the audio output on a *WIRED* headset with a click of a button with following code:

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

and on a Bluetooth headset with the following (not in calls, works on media/music only):

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

I have two problems:

1. When I click on the speaker icon in the call screen to stop using my Bluetooth headset and then click the button on my app to redirct the route to my Bluetooth headset with the above code it doesn't work :(
2. Didn't manage to find a way to broadcast audio output change in order for the above code to work automatically without a need to press my app's button. only came across the following code that only suppose to work on a Bluetooth headset and not plugged headset and it's don't even work for me on the Bluetooth headset.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothHeadset.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
                switch (state) {
                    case BluetoothHeadset.STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTED:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    case BluetoothHeadset.STATE_AUDIO_DISCONNECTED:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
                        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
                        mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Thanks so much in advance for the help!

any answer would help.